# How can I export a scene or movieclip as a SWF without bringing the whole library?

Tags: flash, movieclip, flash-ide

I have an FLA file with numerous scenes.  I need to export a single scene or alternatively a single movieclip as a SWF without exporting the entire FLA library with it in the SWF.  I only want it to export with the symbols and assets used in the scene/movieclip.

I've tried many different settings and methods of exporting, but they all seem to bring the entirety of the FLA library with it.  The only solution I've found so far is to copy/paste the scene's timeline into a new FLA, and export from there.

Does anyone know of a better way to do this?

Thank you.

EDIT: A bit of context may help:

I'm currently using the exported SWF file with a system called UniSWF, a Unity3D asset which converts SWF files into spritesheets and animation sequences for use in games.  When I export a SWF using the right-click in library and export SWF, or the "Test Movie" method from the top menu, UniSWF produes packed textures containing assets from my entire library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After numerous tests, it appears that when exporting a movieclip or a scene in Flash from the library, it will also bring every movieclip in the library with it which has the "Export for ActionScript" property checked.  This seems logical, as the generated AS will have a reference to the movieclip, which brings it into the export.  Unchecking this on all movieclips which should not be exported seems to have resolved the issue when exporting a single moviecip from the library.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply export your MovieClip as an SWF from the library :

[image]

For the scene, you have just to select it and run a scene test via **Control** >> **Test Scene** or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Hope that can help.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer and screenshot.  Unfortunately I've tried this, and this too will export all the assets in the library in the SWF.  The output file size confirms this.  The "Test Scene" function also appears to export the whole library as well.

Comment: @Jeff No, I disagree with you. It will export only the used assets in the exported MovieClip. You can decompile your swf and you will see that ...

Comment: Perhaps some context would help:  I'm currently using the exported SWF file with a system called UniSWF, a Unity3D asset which converts SWF files into spritesheets and animation sequences for use in games.  When I export a SWF using the method you describe, UniSWF produes packed textures containing assets from my entire library.  

The exported SWF file size is also very large, and when exporting from a separate project (via the copy/paste method I described above), I saw a significantly smaller file size.  Perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: I'd like to mention that I am a programmer doing research on behalf of my art team, and if you're 100% sure that this method should not export all library assets, then it's entirely possible the problem is on the art team's end in the way that the scenes are setup perhaps.

Comment: @Jeff I don't know what your MovieClip contain exactly, but yes, I tested that and I decompiled the whole movie's swf and the MovieClip's one and I didn't find some assets which I added to the Flash project in the MovieClip's swf.

Comment: Were those assets that you added to the Flash project being used in another scene within the project?

Comment: @Jeff I'm talking about a MovieClip's export, and that content I added to the same scene as that MovieClip.

Comment: Alright, that gives me some things to investigate. Thanks for your time.